# Code not quite doing what I want it to do. Exits loop early

Tags: java, eclipse

I have written the code (below) and I would like it to add **all the valid integers in the file** and ignore anything that isn't valid. At the moment, it **stops** at **an invalid value** and doesn't continue.

***intnumbers.txt*:**

```
22
33
44
55
66
ss
77
88
99
```

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HandleExceptions {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int total = 0;
        int number;

        try {
            File inFile = new File("intnumbers.txt");
            Scanner fileScanner= new Scanner(inFile);
            while (fileScanner.hasNextInt()) {
                number = fileScanner.nextInt(); // Checks to see the next double in the text file
                total = total + number;
                System.out.println(number);
            }
            fileScanner.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("No such file name");
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.err.println("Data incorrect type expecting an int");
        }

        System.out.println("Finished");
        System.out.println("Total is:" + total);
    }
}
```

***EXAMPLE OUTPUT*:**

```
22
33
44
55
66
Finished
Total is:220
```

Comment: How about scanning them in as strings, parsing them as numbers and continuing if there is an exception due to invalid format?

Comment: Your while doesn't continue after the InputMismatchException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead? Gets a integer when there is one, or just skip it.

```java
int total = 0;
int number;

try {
    File inFile = new File("intnumbers.txt");
    Scanner fileScanner= new Scanner(inFile);
    while (fileScanner.hasNext())
    {
        if(fileScanner.hasNextInt()) // Check for an valid integer
        {
            number = fileScanner.nextInt(); // Gets the integer
            total = total + number;         // Add it to the total
            System.out.println(number);
        }
        else
        {
            fileScanner.next(); // Skip invalid input
            // System.out.println("Data incorrect type, expecting an int");
        }
    }
    fileScanner.close();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.err.println("No such file name");
}
catch (InputMismatchException e)
{
    // If an exception is thrown for an invalid data type
    // Your loop will not run to completion
    System.err.println("Data incorrect type expecting an int");
}

System.out.println("Finished");
System.out.println("Total is:" + total);
```

**Output:**

```
22
33
44
55
66
77
88
99
Finished
Total is:484
```

Answer (score 0):

You use scanner.hasNextInt in your loop. Based on the docs, this returns false as soon as "ss" is read (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29).

One way to get it working would be to use hasNextLine instead in the loop condition and then check if the line is an integer or not.

Answer (score 0):

The condition you are having is `while (fileScanner.hasNextInt())`.

As the name says, `hasNextInt()` will check if the next value is int or not.

When it encounters `ss` then it will return false and exit from loop.

[More Info](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29)

You need to revise your logic by using say, `hasNext()`

**EDIT:**

There will be an exception when you will try to parse the string `ss` to integer, in the line,

`number = fileScanner.nextInt();`

Better you try this statement with try-catch.

```
try{
    number = fileScanner.nextInt();
}catch(NumberFormatException e){

}
```

Comment: has next means that it only displays the error message. the loop still does not continue

Comment: @the_no_1 Check my edit, it is just a hint. You might need to revise your logic.

Answer (score 0):

fileScanner.hasNextInt() returns false if there is not int at next
so while stopped at 'ss' and must be so...

you must write

```
 while (fileScanner.hasNext())
    {
        try{
          number = Integer.pasrseInt(fileScanner.next()); /
        }            
        catch(Exception ex) {}
    }
 )
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does nothing

Answer (score 0):

The [Scanner API doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) describes the functionality of the `hasNextInt` method as follows:

> Returns true if the next token in this scanner's input can be interpreted as an int value in the default radix using the nextInt() method.

Since `ss` cannot be interpreted as an int, the loop will exit. I would suggest using `hasNext` or `hasNextLine()` instead.